# How to group and sort in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in mongodb with mongoose schema

```
var collection = new Schema({
  name : String,
  position : Number,
  category : String
});

collection.index({ category : 1, position : 1 }, { unique : true });
```

Now i want to fetch records in batches such that

it should group all the records on basis of category and then within each category(group), all records should be sorted on basis of position.

For example

i have following collection

```
[
  { name : 'Mr X', position : 34, category : 'U' },
  { name : 'Mr Y', position : 14, category : 'T' },
  { name : 'Mr G', position : 55, category : 'T' },
  { name : 'Mr I', position : 5, category : 'L' },
  { name : 'Mr D', position : 51, category : 'L' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 14, category : 'U' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 20, category : 'U' },
  { name : 'Mr E', position : 14, category : 'L' }
]
```

Now what should be the efficient query for this?

I am trying to fetch 3rd batch (each batch of 2 records)

```
db.ask.aggregate([{
            $group : {
                _id : "$category"
            }
        }, {
            $sort : {
                position : 1
            }
        }, {
            $skip : 4
        }, {
            $limit : 2
        }
    ])
```

And i am expecting output :

```
[
  { name : 'Mr G', position : 55, category : 'T' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 14, category : 'U' }
]
```

but actually getting none.

If fetching all records (without any batches), the expected output should be

```
[
  { name : 'Mr I', position : 5, category : 'L' },
  { name : 'Mr E', position : 14, category : 'L' }
  { name : 'Mr D', position : 51, category : 'L' },
  { name : 'Mr Y', position : 14, category : 'T' },
  { name : 'Mr G', position : 55, category : 'T' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 14, category : 'U' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 20, category : 'U' },
  { name : 'Mr X', position : 34, category : 'U' },
]
```

EDIT : I am looking for a query that is flexible to my changing requirements.
what if i want to bring first category T then L then U.?

So my expected output (with limits and skip) was supposed to be

```
[
  { name : 'Mr I', position : 5, category : 'L' },
  { name : 'Mr P', position : 14, category : 'U' }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your requirements, you do not want to group at all but just want to sort by two fields and then do more or less some kind of paging.
That said, with the following aggregation pipeline I got your desired result.

```
db.ask.aggregate([
    { 
        $sort : {
            category : 1,
            position : 1 
        } 
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : 0,
            category : 1,
            position : 1,
            name : 1
        }
    },
    {  
        $skip : 4
    },
    {
        $limit : 2
    },
])
```

Comment: what if want to change the order of category, first T then L then U?? See my edit please

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to group on compound key to get desired result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$group : { _id : {category:"$category", position:"$position", name:"$name"}}}, 
 {$project:{_id:0, category:"$_id.category", name:"$_id.name", position:"$_id.position"}},
 {$sort : {"category" : 1, position:1} }, 
 {$skip : 4 }, 
 {$limit : 2 } 
])
```

This will print:

```
{ 
    "category" : "T", 
    "name" : "Mr G", 
    "position" : 55.0
}
{ 
    "category" : "U", 
    "name" : "Mr P", 
    "position" : 14.0
}
```

Comment: what if want to change the order of category, first T then L then U?? See my edit please

Comment: Well, go ahead and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to group and other aggregation stages
just sort on correct fields

we can  have `normal`  query

```
db.codofoode.find()
.sort({
    category : 1,
    position : 1
}).skip(4).limit(2)
```

or aggregate

```
db.codofoode.aggregate([
{
            $sort : {
              category:1,   position : 1
            }
        },

        {
            $skip : 4
        },
        {
            $limit : 2
        }])
```

Comment: what if want to change the order of category, first T then L then U?? See my edit please

Comment: as you are expecting results in ascending order and we are sorting in ascending order, then result set will pass requested test criteria :-)